# Prove: $\exists a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ not all zero, $|a|,|b|,|c|<10^6$ s.t. $|a+\sqrt2 b+\sqrt 3 c|\leq\frac{1+\sqrt2 +\sqrt3}{1+10^6+10^{12}}$

Tags: combinatorics

Show that there are integers $a,b,c$ not all zero, with absolute values less than $10^6$ such that
$$|a+\sqrt2 b+\sqrt 3 c|\leq\frac{1+\sqrt2 +\sqrt3}{1+10^6+10^{12}}.$$

I have the read the Putnam Solution for similar question, I don't understand the part that they get the inequality and then apply Pigeonhole theorem there.
Link: https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol804.html
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Can we do anything about this expression (a + b √2 + c √3)?
Such as finding a, b, c?

Comment: **Markdown Editing Help**: https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help , **How do I ask a good question**: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask , **MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference**: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{ a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} \mid 0 \leq a,b,c \leq 10^6 -1 \}$. Each element of this set lies in the interval $[0,(10^6-1) \times (1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})]$. Now divide this interval into $10^{18} -1$ consecutive subintervals of length $\frac{(10^6-1) \times (1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})}{10^{18} -1}$. By the pigeonhole principle, we have that at least two elements of $A$ lie in the same subinterval. So the difference of these numbers is our desired number.